# root@localhost's password: localhost: Permission denied, please try again

Tags: ssh, openssh, hadoop

I am trying to setup Hadoop in "Pseudo-distributed Mode". I have already performed the below steps:

- I have installed `Openssh-server`.
- I have generated the rsa type key pair.
- Copied *rsa.pub to authorized_keys folder for the current user.
- I gave chmod 600 permissions for authorized_keys file.
- I have set `PermitRootLogin yes` in the `sudo gedit /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

I am able to login as `ssh localhost` which is not asking for password. But when running `sudo /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.3/sbin/start-dfs.sh` asks for root password. If i do provide root password then also it does not allow.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source and destination users are different, and that should be the reason of this. Would suggest you trying to start Hadoop daemons without sudo. ssh is actually from one user@host to another user@host pair. When you skip target user in your ssh command it is assumed to be same as the source user. But here your source user becomes root as you are using sudo while the destination user is still kashif.

HTH